# How to know whether fuse is sufficient for electrical device?

Tags: electrical

How can I find out from the information about an electrical device whether fuse and wiring is sufficient for that particular device?

For example, we are considering buying a septic pump; from the information on the producer website about various types they make, I see pumps with power 1.5 kW and with power 0.8 kW (both for 230 V). Is it ok to plug such device into normal AC power plug. Or would it be better to buy a device with smaller power output, just to be on the safe side?

P.S. Sorry for my English. I hope the post is understandable. (I did not talk in English  about things like this before. I'll be grateful for terminology corrections.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1500 W/ 230 V = 6.5 A

800 W / 230 V = 3.5 A

Now, a fused circuit should normally be loaded to 80% capacity.  So on a dedicated circuit, you would need an 8 A or 4.5 A fuse.

But, usually circuits feed more than one outlet.  So you need to find out what else is being fed by the same fuse.  Most devices will have a sticker declaring the draw.  Add up the amps, add in your pump, and stay withing the 80% capacity limit.  If you go over, add another breaker/fuse and make it a dedicated circuit.  If amps aren't posted,   W/230 will give you the current draw.

Answer (score 1):

what is the purpose of a fuse? It is used to protect the cables! So it depends from (thinnest)  cable used. e.g. you can use up to 16A fuse to protect cable with at least 1.5mm^2 copper. depends on environment temperature and length. The max power consumption can be 16A*230V= 3680W or 3.6kW